# In Unity .Net WebSocket, solving SendAsync "already one outstanding" problem

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, websocket

In Unity with .Net I'm using websockets, so as a client:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
async void Connect()
{
    cws = new ClientWebSocket();
    try
    {
        await cws.ConnectAsync(u, CancellationToken.None);
        if (cws.State == WebSocketState.Open) Debug.Log("connected");
        ... begin receive result loop, etc ...
    }
    catch (Exception e) { Debug.Log("woe " + e.Message); }
}
```

To send to the server, I use:

```
public async void SendString(string msg)
{
    ArraySegment<byte> b = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg));
    await cws.SendAsync(b, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Hence throughout the app,

```
ThatClass.SendString("some command");
```

and

```
ThatClass.SendString("some other command");
```

However at one point I do this,

```
ThatClass.SendString("a command");
ThatClass.SendString("another command");
```

**One immediately after another.**

Of course, it doesn't work.  The error is

> InvalidOperationException: **There is already one outstanding 'SendAsync' call for this WebSocket instance.** ReceiveAsync and SendAsync can be called simultaneously, but at most one outstanding operation for each of them is allowed at the same time.
> System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ThrowIfOperationInProgress (System.Threading.Tasks.Task operationTask, System.String methodName) (at :0)
> System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.SendAsync (System.ArraySegment`1[T] buffer, System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType messageType, System.Boolean endOfMessage, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) (at :0)

Is there a simple solution here?  Or do you have to build a queue?

I thought perhaps Monitor would help, so

```
public async void SendString(string msg)
{
    ArraySegment<byte> b = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg));
    //await cws.SendAsync(b, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

    Monitor.Enter(cws);
    try
    {
        cws.SendAsync(b, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(cws);
    }
}
```

However, in that case I get this error:

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) (at :0)
> System.IO.Stream+<>c.b__43_1 (System.IO.Stream stream, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) (at <980ae0ed635b4a3296831396fcc0a4a0>:0)
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1+FromAsyncTrimPromise`1[TResult,TInstance].Complete (TInstance thisRef, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] endMethod, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) (at <980ae0ed635b4a3296831396fcc0a4a0>:0)

Is there a simple solution?  (Or any solution!)

---

As a curiosity (this could be Unity related, IDK) if you add any statement between the two calls,

```
ThatClass.SendString("a command");
x = 1;
ThatClass.SendString("another command");
```

disturbingly, it then does work!  :O (As often as I tested it.)

Comment: PS for anyone googling here, in practice nowadays in Unity you basically **must** use the socket library https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client (it's the only currently maintained one - as of 2021 )  It would be totally impractical to start from scratch and - essentially - write that library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be awating the `SendAsync` call and return a `Task` that represents this operation. If you do not await the call, the flow of the method continues before finishing the execution of `SendAsync`. Try this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public async Task SendStringAsync(string msg)
{
    ArraySegment<byte> b = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg));

    Monitor.Enter(cws);
    try
    {
        await cws.SendAsync(b, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(cws);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
await mySockerWrapper.SendStringAsync("Hello World!");
```

Comment: I would not lock the entire `cws` object to make sure that only one write operation can be done at a time. Instead I would either create a `sendLock` or make sure that only one type of event (like receiving something) can trigger a send.

Comment: `private object _sendLock = new object();`.  and then `Monitor.Enter` as in the code. so it's minimal difference make the intent is much more clear and you don't have to worry that something in your code will lock `cws` for other purposes and by doing that degrade performance.

Comment: I can see that the fact is you have to have a QUEUE for outgoing messages.